# mail function only sending on first instance

Tags: php, email

i have a some code which sends an email to me and to another address.
However, it only sends to the first call of the mail() function in the code. i.e. the first iteration works but not the second. Its not the email address that the issue because if i flip them it works. any suggestions?

```
<?PHP    
$to = 'email1@test.com';
$subject = 'test title 1';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test 1</h1>
<p>test 1</p>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: Test <donotreply@test.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

$to = 'email2@test.com';
$subject = 'test title 2';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test 2</h1>
<p>test 2</p>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: Test <donotreply@test.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Comment: you do not need to specify headers array again for second mail.You can also have string concatenation for headers as well like `$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'; $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';`

Comment: So is the issue here multiple duplicate headers?  I've read error messages from servers that forbid multiple `from` headers, but can't find any reference in the RFCs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's send only one email because **$headers[]** array.

```
<?PHP   
$headers1 = $headers2 = array(); 
$to = 'email1@test.com';
$subject = 'test title 1';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test 1</h1>
<p>test 1</p>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers1[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers1[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers1[] = 'From: Test <donotreply@test.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers1));

$to = 'email2@test.com';
$subject = 'test title 2';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test 2</h1>
<p>test 2</p>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers2[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers2[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers2[] = 'From: Test <donotreply@test.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers2));
```

Comment: Why should we have same array twice?

Comment: for now **From: Test <donotreply@test.com>** data is same but in set it may change that is reason for array use  twice.